# PHP array to JavaScript array via Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want the result of this Ajax request to fill the JavaScript `hintArray`. That is, I want `hintArray` to contain the same values as `$row`. Can this be done in a simple way?
How should the php file output be made?
Is `hintArray = JSON.parse(this);` correct?

Many thanks

**JavaScript**

```
var hintArray = new Array();
postAjaxRequestFunktion(minFunktion, 'getHint.php', 'id =1')
function minFunktion()
{
  hintArray = JSON.parse(this); 

}

function postAjaxRequestFunktion(minFunk,minUrl, mittArg)
{
   var contenttype = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
   var minRequest        = new skapaAjaxObjekt(minFunk)
   if (!minRequest) return false
   minRequest.open('POST', minUrl, true)
   minRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type',   contenttype)
   minRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-length', mittArg.length)
   minRequest.setRequestHeader('Connection',     'close')
   minRequest.send(mittArg)
   return true
}

function skapaAjaxObjekt(minFunk)
{
   try       { var   minRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()                   }
   catch(e1) { try { minRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")    }
   catch(e2) { try { minRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") }
   catch(e3) { minRequest = false }}}
   if (minRequest) minRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
   {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 &&
          this.responseText != null)
            minFunk.call(this.responseText)
   }

   return minRequest
}
```

**getHint.php**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT hint01,hint02 FROM main WHERE id = '00000001'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should encode your php array with

```
json_encode($your_array);
```

and decode it in javascript with eval

```
your_js_array = eval('(' + yourJSONtext + ')');
```

Comment: I added this to the .php file:
echo json_encode($row);
And this to JS:
function minFunktion()
         {
 hintArray = eval('(' + this + ')'); 
         }
But it doesn't work. The JS array is empty. What am I doing wrong?
If I instead add this to JS:
function minFunktion()
         {
           document.getElementById('hint').innerHTML = this
         }
This is written in the hint element:
["hintText1"," hintText2"]

Comment: has "this" a value? use console.info(this); or console.info(this.responseText); .Are you receiving something??

Comment: I did a mistake but rectified it and now your solution works perfectly. Many thanks for showing me this simple way to solve it!